# How to create dummy variables using various columns sharing same levels and using a specific column value

Tags: r, linear-regression, dummy-variable

I am trying to get the dummy variables for the following table:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Value1 = c(9.330154398, 32.43881489, 54.77178387, 54.77178387),
                      Value2 = c(1, 2, 3, 8),
                      var1 = c("HomeATL", "AwaySDN", "AwayLAN", "AwayLAN"),
                      var2 = c("AwayHOU", "HomeATL", "HomeATL", "HomeATL"),
                      var3 = c("HomeEast", "HomeWest", "AwayEast", "AwayWest"),
                      var3values = c(1,2,3,4),
                      var4 = c("AwayWest", "AwayWest", "HomeSame", "HomeEast"),
                      var4values = c(5,6,7,8)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

The result should look like:

```
Value1         Value2   HomeEast    HomeWest    AwayEast    AwayWest    HomeSame    HomeATL AwayHOU AwaySDN AwayLAN
9.330154398        1    1   0   0   5   0   1   1   0   0
-32.43881489       2    0   2   0   6   0   1   0   1   0
54.77178387        3    0   0   3   0   7   1   0   0   1
54.77178387        8    8   0   0   4   0   1   0   0   1
```

I have already asked something similar and the  approach I have used was:

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>%
    gather(key, val, var1:var4) %>% 
    count(rn, val) %>%
    spread(val, n, fill = 0)  %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    bind_cols(df1[1:2], .)
```

However, It returns the dummy values with 1 or 0 and not the values of some predefined column.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
one <- df1 %>% select(var1:var2) %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
gather(key, val, var1:var2) %>% mutate(key = 1) %>% 
spread(val, key, fill = 0) %>% select(-rn)


two <- df1 %>% select(var3:var3values) %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% rename(var = 
var3, values = var3values)  %>% 
 bind_rows(df1 %>% 
          select(var4:var4values) %>% 
          rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
          rename(var = var4, values = var4values)) %>% 
  spread(var, values, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-rn)

  three <- df1 %>% select(1,2) 

    cbind(three, two, one)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to `gather` the columns that `matches` column name that starts with 'var' followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string, grouped by the row number, 'val' column, create 'n' based on a condition specified in `case_when` i.e. if the 'key' is 'var3', then get the corresponding values of 'var3values', or if it is 'var4', get 'var4values' and if both of them are not the case, then get the frequency count (`n()`), `spread` it to 'wide' format and keep only the columns of interest

```
 rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>%
    gather(key, val, matches("^var\\d+$")) %>%
    group_by(rn, val) %>% 
    mutate(n = case_when(key == "var3" ~ var3values, 
                         key == "var4" ~ var4values,
                         TRUE ~ as.numeric(n()))) %>% 
    select(-var3values, -var4values, -key) %>%
    spread(val, n, fill = 0) %>%  
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 4 x 11
#  Value1 Value2 AwayEast AwayHOU AwayLAN AwaySDN AwayWest HomeATL HomeEast HomeSame HomeWest
#   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1   9.33      1        0       1       0       0        5       1        1        0        0
#2  32.4       2        0       0       0       1        6       1        0        0        2
#3  54.8       3        3       0       1       0        0       1        0        7        0
#4  54.8       8        0       0       1       0        4       1        8        0        0
```